# Why is the sigmoid activation function better than the sign function?

Tags: neural-networks

I would like to know why we don't just use the sign function if it caps it off at 0 or 1 anyway.

Comment: Do you mean the sign function that only gives values of 0 and 1? And do you mean as an activation function?

Comment: Perhaps because choice is binary but certainty is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backprop requires differentiable functions with nonzero gradients in a meaningful portion of their domain. The derivative of the sign function is zero almost everywhere so weights will never update.

Comment: great, thank you. Would you possibly be able to point me to some mathematical proof? I understand what you mean, but not definitively.

Comment: furthermore, why is a sigmoid more powerful in general?

Comment: To prove this, just write down the backprop for two networks, one using sigmoid and one using sign. Because the derivative of the sign function is 0 almost everywhere, the weights will never move. The sigmoid derivative is never 0 anywhere (though it does become small), so it does not exhibit this behavior.